# How to find the general solution of this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been assigned the following partial differential equation as an introductory exercise:

$$u_{xy}+au_x+bu_y+abu=0$$

Where $a,b$ are constants and $u=u(x,y)$. Having seen barely anything except for a couple easy examples, I have no clue how to even start. We haven't seen any actual solving methods, and so far we've only executed a single change of variables, d'Alembert's one for solving the vibrant chord, so I'm assuming a change of variables should solve this, but we haven't discussed any intuition to choose the change.

I have basic knowledge (one semester) on ordinary differential equations, so if this can be reduced to one of the simple types I should be able to solve it.

I've tried a linear change of variables and then trying to adjust the constants:

$$\xi=Ax+By$$
$$\eta=Cx+Dy$$

Plugging the result in the equation I couldn't adjust the constants to get something easy enough to solve.

Comment: Doesn't writing it as $v_x+bv=0$ help?

Comment: That could help, the problem is I don't understand how you get to that, is $v$ a different function or some particular case?

Comment: Use the substitution $v=u_y+au$.

Comment: Ah I see, that's nice, I guess when you're just starting there's a lot of things you don't notice. I'm trying to solve it now using that.

Comment: Wow, I think I got it. So, essentially the idea with this kind of substitions is to solve the resulting equation, and then use that back in the substition to get the function $u$, in this case solving the ODE $u_y = -au -v$, is this correct?

Comment: Oops, I meant $u_y=v-au$.